# CSS "width: 100%" lagging

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a page with the following setup:

```html
...
  <td>
    <code>...</code> <!-- At least 10,000 of these! -->
  </td>
...
```

In my CSS I have

```css
code {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that this lags terribly when loading, since it has to load all `<code>` elements before it can display even the first, since it has to calculate the final width based on the longest one.

Is there any way to speed this up? I would just like the first few lines displayed right away. It can resize itself after it finishes loading them all.

Comment: add visibility hidden to your body tag and on window.load change it to visible

Comment: With `visibility:hidden` the browser still calculates width, just doesn't show the element. In order to not calculate the element at all, you can use `display:none` and then change it to `inline` after the document loads, but then you'll have a drastic rearrangement of the page after it's loaded.

Comment: If you want to use `width: 100%` then why using `display: inline-block`? I think you can just use `display: block` or `width: 100%` instead of using both css properties.

Comment: How do you populate the table, can you show us some code?

Comment: Why are you even displaying 10.000+ x lines of code in a single page? Have you consider to break them down into multiple pages in order to make this more user friendly?

Comment: I've heard that using tables causes pages to load slower.

Comment: @PatsyIssa Not displaying anything until the page loads is the current behavior that I am trying to work around.

Comment: @jegesh See my comment above

Comment: @FabianFreytag What does that have to do with it? The whole table is 1 row, 2 cols. The second `<td>` has this inside it. It is generated by a script that reads a file and surrounds every line with `<code>`. It is irrelevant to the problem, though.

Comment: @Thanos Not an option, but thank you. The displayed file is actually a log, and the user has to be able to jump around the whole thing.

Comment: It is not irrelevant. How frequently your script triggers the render process is critical.

Comment: @FabianFreytag It is generated and rendered once at page-load, or it can be generated server-side if needed. It is static content once the page is loaded.

Comment: Have you compared both ways? The server side generated html should only trigger one render process, while the script might take more, depending on the implementation. If you write to the DOM in each iteration of your loop, you trigger multiple render passes. But if you build a string representing your html and set it via element.innerHTML only one render process is triggered.

Comment: @FabianFreytag I am only doing one render. I am building the whole DOM of the table in a fragment, and appending it to the `td`

Comment: I did some tests: rendering your 10000 elements takes like 5 seconds in chrome on my system. In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shiddzoid/8kVnG/4/ i tried to populate your table chunk wise, so the renderer could keep pace. It's rather slow but kind of responsive. Just play around with the workChunk and delay vars and find your best solution.